# What is this blue circles in gradle beside? And how to disable this?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Today I have seen such blue circles beside to dependency

[image]

And I can't understand is it new feature from AndroidStudio or is it some plugins?

The main issue is as you can see on screenshot dependency marked with a gray collor and made diable to edit them... For example if I would like to update dependency to change the number for instance from 2 to 3, I don't able to do it...

What is it and how to disable this feature?

**EDIT**

new screenshot

[image]

As you see when I put mouse on this line this line turn into correct annotation

Comment: Where are you seeing this, specifically? It would not appear to be a `build.gradle` file, as that syntax is invalid.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean? It is my gradle file... And on screenshot it is list of dependences... Why did you say it is invalid?

Comment: All of the gray entries are missing quotation marks and have invalid stuff after the version number (e.g., additional numbers in square brackets). That is not valid syntax for Gradle dependencies. What version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: @CommonsWare I confused you, because of my english. This gray entries it is just consequences of this plagin. In real it has correct annotation, but this plugin tern into such precentation. When I put the mouse on any of line it is shows correctly. I attechec one more screenshot it makes it easy to understand

Comment: @CommonsWare I am running Android Studio 2.2.2

Comment: I have Android Studio 2.2.2, and I do not see this behavior. Perhaps this is some plugin that you installed.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes eventually I figered out what it was. The reason this plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8076

Comment: I suggest that you add that as an answer for your question, so others searching Stack Overflow will see that the question has been answered. But I'm glad to see that you found out the source of the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

Eventuallu I figered out the reason of it. Because I plug in this library in my project

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8076

all that I needed just to plug out